# Do violate salesforce contract if integration user create cases via API instead of a customer from a custom portal?

Tags: api, integration, customer-community, servicecloud

I work for a company that sells enterprise saas software, we manage cases in the service cloud, I am working on a solution wherein we want to build a functionality that will allow our customers to submit cases from our product instead of asking customers to log in to a salesforce community.

Question: Can we use an integration user to create cases via API instead of the customer? Are there any license implications/salesforce contract violations if we do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your not logging in to Salesforce, there'd be no license violation. You'd simply be sending cases to your customer's Salesforce Org via integration which could take many forms. It's really no different than having the customer submit email to case, web to case or importing cases from a back end system like SAP via integration into your org. You could use REST, SOAP, ETL or other means to import records into the org via an API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can use an integration user to create cases via the Rest Api. I don't see how you would be violating any usage restriction. You just have to be mindful of the amount of Api calls your integration does, as it may impact costs.